# Does closed Port 25 cause mail to be marked as spam?

Tags: iptables, postfix, smtp, port, email-server

I have a web server where I have installed Postfix for sending emails only. All incoming mails will be handled by google apps and not my web server. Using iptables rules, I have blocked all incoming ports (including Port 25) and opened only ssh and http ports. All Outbound traffic are open. From testing I can see that postfix is able to send emails even when port 25 is blocked so that is not an issue. My understanding was Port 25 is only needed to be opened if I am receiving emails on that server. But I read this in [coding horror site](http://blog.codinghorror.com/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code/) that has confused me a bit:

> Port25 offers a really nifty public service -- you can send email to
>   check-auth@verifier.port25.com and it will reply to the from: address
>   with an extensive diagnostic!

So my question is, does some mail server ping my Port 25 to check the authenticity of my server origin when Postfix sends email to them? If Postfix is used to send emails only, do I still need to open Port 25 so other mail servers can verify my server info? I am concerned if I block port 25, is that another reason for some email clients to mark my emails as Spam because they are unable to get info on my server by pinging to Port 25? I cant find info on this. I will be obliged if someone can clarify this plz...

Comment: Outbound and inbound mail are completely unrelated services. In fact, only if an outbound mail server *is* capable of receiving mail as well, it is a candidate for being an open relay. And a backward connection attempt for each outgoing mail is certainly not desireable - not to mention that it would allow a DDOS attack via IP spoofing.

Comment: So for a send only postfix server, it is secure to have the port 25 closed isint it. In my logs I can still see some ip addresses trying to connect to post 25 even when they are closed. When you say 'backward connection attempt' do you mean ip addresses trying to connect to smtp port looking to take advantage?

Comment: Note that the "Port25" talked about by Coding Horror is actually a company/service, not the generic "port 25" on a server. Yeah, their name is confusing, but it's not related to *your* server in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some receiving mail servers will check whether the originating server is fully capable of receiving mails at your address.
Others won't accept mails sent from dialup IP ranges.

As you said your incoming mails will be handled by Google Apps, why not send your outgoing mails right through Google, too?

Comment: I am going to be using my server Postfix to send trasanction emails, newsletter emails, etc.. and thats why I am not using Google for outgoing for emails from my site since if I remember correctly, Google has a limit on how many emails you can send and we are not allowed to use Google app for transactional email.

Comment: When you say some mail servers will expect the originating server for receiving mails at that address, would they still need to check that when my MX records shows Google app for receiving and A Record, SPF, etc.. confirming the ipaddress of my web server? This is the part I am unsure about..

Comment: Well, if SPF confirms that you're allowed to send from your server for your domain, I guess we're fine here.

Comment: Thank you @vautee... Then I guess it's fine to have port 25 closed as long as we have other things set up like sfp, dkim, rdns, etc..